# child theme is not loading whole style from parent theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

this is my test page e-commerce shop: https://shop.amir-rahbaran.com/

this is the parent style:
https://colorlib.com/shapely

`functions.php:`

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

The **shapely-master** (parent) and **shapely-child** are both located in the **theme** folder (same hierarchy).

This is my **shapely-child** `style.css`:

```
/*
Theme Name: Shapely-Child
Template: shapely
Theme URI: https://colorlib.com/wp/themes/shapely
Author: colorlib - modified by Sandra J. / Amir R.
Author URI: https://colorlib.com/
Description: [...]
Version: 1.0.5
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: shapely
[ ... ]
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you can try replacing the code of function my_theme_enqueue_styles with the following modified code.

```
  function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('shapely-bootstrap') );
    wp_dequeue_style('shapely-style');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'shapely-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}
```

To resolve the issue please make change in the function my_theme_enqueue_styles as i have described above and then change the following line in the style.css file of your child theme

Template: shapely

with the following line.

Template: shapely-master

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this didn’t do the trick. Maybe the new info from my side helps? Thx, Amir

Comment: Thank you for providing more info about your child theme. Please see my modified answer above.

Comment: I have modified the above shared function my_theme_enqueue_styles so please try using that.

Answer (score 0):

In this way, it will not work :

```
wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/shop.amir-rahbaran.com/wp-content/themes/shapely-master/style.css' );
```

Because the result of the enqueue is an incorrect stylesheet path :

```
../wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/shop.amir-rahbaran.com/wp-content/themes/shapely-master/style.css
```

After checking your website source code with inspection tool, it seems is working.

I have tested too the following function, and it works:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Still not working for you?

Comment: Well it works but not completely. The buttons are not displayed correctly. This is how they should look like:
https://colorlib.com/shapely/